# What words are the choral singers singing in 'Hope'?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

At the start of *[Hope](http://michaelgiacchino.com/projects/rogue-one-star-wars-story/)* (by Michael Giacchino), taken from the Rogue One soundtrack, there is a chorale singing what sounds like chanted Latin.

**What are they singing? Are there any available lyrics?**

Comment: Easily answerable (meaning - at least one person knows the answer...the trick is will he tell us :) no reason to vtc. Also - I think this person might be on to something that the chords sung are very similar to the Imperial March - https://genius.com/Michael-giacchino-hope-lyrics

Comment: @NKCampbell - I'm assuming the singers also know what they were singing.

Comment: @Valorum for me, sounds like harmonic choirs, i.e. no words.

Comment: @TimSparrow - I thought that at first, but there are a couple of places where they seem to be singing words not just inchoate noises

Comment: If the first two words sound like "Lorem ipsum", we can stop this right here.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - O! Excrementum! suus Vader! Curre!

Comment: FYI, I've tweeted at the composer. Hopefully he'll respond

Comment: Could be "He’s Here For Us", just like 1st track title from the album.

Comment: In [Music from Rogue One: A Star Wars Story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvunAQ5vaq8&t=795s) there is a very different choral, could anyone recognize it? Or  is it different because the original one is a secret?

Comment: Seems that second one was performed by [Czech Studio Orchestra and Ondrej Vrabec (?)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtHxaU-P5GE)